# Bounds on the number of integer compositions with parts bounded from above and below

Tags: co.combinatorics, asymptotics, generating-functions

I'm looking for asymptotic bounds (as n goes to infinity) on the number of integer compositions of $n$ with parts in $[a,n]$ and separately for parts in $[a,b]$, with $1 < a < b < n$.

(To clarify, $n$ varies, $a$ and $b$ are fixed)

Relevant results I'm aware of, although not exactly what I'm looking for, are the following:

Jaklič, G., Vitrih, V. & Žagar, E. CLOSED FORM FORMULA FOR THE NUMBER OF RESTRICTED COMPOSITIONS. Bull. Aust. Math. Soc. 81, 289–297 (2010).

Malandro, M. E. Integer compositions with part sizes not exceeding k. arXiv:1108.0337 [math] (2012).

Comment: A lot will depend on how $a$ and $b$ can vary with $n$. What are your requirements?

Comment: Thanks. $a$ and $b$ are fixed. I'm specifically interested in whether superpolynomial lower bounds can be proven for the case where parts $x_i \in [a, n]$ and for the case where $x_i \in [a,b]$, $x_i$ being the summands in the integer composition. The case where $x_i \in [1, b]$ is already obtained in Malandro (2012). I would also be interested in whether polynomial upper bounds can be proven, if the above is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

From the generating function:
$$\frac1{1-(x^a+x^{a+1}+\dots+x^b)}=\frac{1-x}{1-x-x^a+x^{b+1}}$$
it follows that the number of compositions of $n$ with parts in $[a,b]$ (given by the coefficient of $x^n$) grows proportionally to $|\alpha|^{-n}$, where $\alpha$ is the smallest by absolute value zero of $1-x-x^a+x^{b+1}$.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate, step by step with rationale, and perhaps relate the $[a,b]$ case to the $[a,n]$ case?

Comment: @blizzard, the $[a, n]$ case corresponds to g.f. $\frac{1}{1 - (x^a + x^{a+1} + \cdots)} = \frac{1-x}{1-x - x^a}$. Partial fraction decomposition turns a rational function $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ into a sum of fractions $\frac{P_\alpha(x)}{x - \alpha} = \frac{-\alpha^{-1} P_\alpha(x)}{1 - \alpha^{-1}x} = -\alpha^{-1}P_{\alpha}(x)(1 + \alpha^{-1}x + \alpha^{-2}x^2 + \cdots)$ where the $\alpha$ are the roots of $Q$.

Comment: It's pretty standard argument - e.g. see Chapter 5 in the [generatingfunctionology](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfology2.pdf) book.

Comment: Using the original gf it is easy to see that the complex zero with the smallest absolute value is the smallest positive real zero.

Comment: The g.f. I arrive to (take the $[a, n]$ case as example) is different from the above by a factor of $\frac{x^a}{1-x}$. This is because $x^a + x^{a+1} + ... = x^a(1 + x^1 + x^2 + ...) = x^a \frac{1}{1-x}$ and this to the $k$-th power is for compositions of $k$ parts. Therefore we need to sum over $k$, and this gives $$\sum_k (\frac{x^a}{1-x})^k = \frac{x^a}{1-x} \frac{1}{1 - \frac{x^a}{(1-x)}} = \frac{x^a}{1-x-x^a}$$. Is there a mistake in the answer above or in the steps here?

Comment: @blizzard: Both Peter and I sum over $k\geq0$, while you sum over $k\geq1$. The extra factor you get does not affect the asymptotic though.

Comment: Anybody mind unpacking $|\alpha|^{-n}$ and its interpretation in terms of growth of the sequence of coefficients?

Comment: @blizzard: I'm not sure what mean under "unpacking". Its interpretation is that the coefficient of $x^n$ is [big-Theta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations) of $|\alpha|^{-n}$.

Comment: It would be nice to have the steps that take you from the generating function to the result more explicit. A high-level description of the steps can also help. Otherwise, where can we find a nice, gentle explanation of these steps?

Comment: @blizzard, the second comment on this answer gives the high-level description and the third comment gives a reference to a book for the nice, gentle explanation.

Comment: Thanks but I've (obviously) already read the above and references. My comment can be read as "more explicit high-level description" and "nice[r] and gentle[r] explanation".

Comment: @blizzard: If the book reference is not enough for you, you'd better seek help at https://math.stackexchange.com/ Please notice that MathOverflow is for professional mathematicians (who typically can digest references by themselves).

Comment: Digesting then, different $a, b$ will yield different asymptotics then, correct? Because they determine different roots of the denominator of the generating function. Perhaps this is what @BrendanMcKay meant above? Hence there's no general asymptotic for arbitrary $a$ and $b$ in the range indicated above.

Comment: @blizzard  Why would you expect different problems to have the same asymptotics?  But the nature of the asymptotics is the same: $\sim C \alpha^{-n}$ where $C$ and $\alpha$ are constants depending on $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I mean "same/different" only in the narrow sense of different problems (various combinations of $a$ and $b$) yielding exponential (or not) growth rates of the number of compositions.